how to prevent logout after i click refresh
so i use reactjs as frontend and express in backend , I use jwt in backend and i set token expiresIn 2h so when i logs in it returns me token and returns my user details in jwt.verify method too but after i log in i set token in cookies but once i refresh the page the token is still in cookies but it logs out
Reactjs code :
const [userName , setUsername]=useState(""); // Store user name from fetch 
                                                res data
const [isLoggedIn,setLogin]=useState(false)  // if fetch is true from 
                                              backend it set as True

useEffect(()=>{
async function fetchData(){
let res =await axios.post('https://localhost:3030/login',data,{
        withCredentials : true } );

if(res.status === 200){
    setUsername(res.data.name);
     setLogin(true);
}
fetchData()
},[])
export function Home(){
  return(
      { isLoggedIn ? <p> Welcome {userName}  </p> : <p> Please Login </p> }
)
}

so here if i logged in the p tag displays welcome user if login correctly but after i refresh it logs out as "Please login" but token is in cookie
backend :
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true
}))
app.use(cookieParser())
routes.post('/login', userLogin)

login.js

export const userLogin = async(req, res) => {
    let userVar;
    const { nameLogin, passwordLogin } = req.body;
    if (!nameLogin) {
        return res.status(400).send("Please Enter Name or Mail");
    }
    if (!passwordLogin) {
        return res.status(400).send("Enter your password");
    }

    const emailExp = /^[a-zA-Z][^\s@][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]+$/
    const userExp = emailExp.test(nameLogin);
    try {
        if (userExp) {
            userVar = await UsersModel.findOne({
                email: nameLogin
            })
        } else {
            userVar = await UsersModel.findOne({
                name: nameLogin
            })
        }
        if (!userVar) {
            return res.status(400).send("Invalid username or mail");
        }
        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(passwordLogin, userVar.password);
        if (!passwordMatch) {
            return res.status(400).send("Invalid Password")
        }
        if (passwordMatch) {
            let token = generateJWTtoken(userVar._id);
            res.cookie('token', token, {
                httpOnly: true,
                maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                sameSite: 'lax',
                secure: false
            })

            console.log(req.cookies.token)
            return res.status(200).json({
                "name": userVar.name,
                "data": userVar
            })
        }


    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(400).send("Error")
    }

}


jwtTokenGenerate:
 return jwt.sign({
            userID: id,
        }, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
            expiresIn: '2h'
        })

jwtVerifyMiddleware :
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { UsersModel } from '../Models/User.js';
import { configDotenv } from "dotenv";
configDotenv()
export const verifyJWTtoken = (req, res, next) => {
    let token = req.cookies.token
    if (!token) {
        return res.status(200).send("Might error at Login due to tokens");
    }
    try {
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, async(err, decode) => {
            if (err) {
                return err
            }
            let user = await UsersModel.findById(decode.userID);
            if (!user) {
                return res.status(400).send("User not found");
            }
            req.user = user
            console.log(req.user) // displays the details
            next()
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

so the console.logs the token and as well user data , so did i miss anything ?? it logs out if i hit refresh but cookie has token

Where/what is the code that decides if the user should go to the logon screen or not?

@adsy sorry for that i should write that , but now i done the edit on post  , Thanks

Can we see the whole of userLogin also (the handler of /login)? On the face of it it looks like a software design issue. When you refresh the page, the username and password the user entered is gone, they are only held in memory. That means it will post to /login with the valid cookie yes, but also with empty user/pass in data which will likely invalidate the session. You need a new /user/me endpoint that is requested when the app mounts, and checks the cookie and returns the user details if valid, otherwise something else like false. Then the app decides if to go to logon.

@adsy thank u for response , I done edit the question , oh i thought the issue in frontend , or can u see the backend code and check

so i tried like using js-cookies   const token = Cookies.get('token');
console.log(token)
and it shows undefined
@adsy

so i tried like using js-cookies   const token = Cookies.get('token');
console.log(token)
and it shows undefined and tried Cookies.get() and it shows a style cookie but not token cookie and i checked on Application in devTools in localhost:3000 (which is react port ) the token cookie is there   and i checked req and res headers as well it has Set-Cookie with token='tokens' , sorry im new to react    @adsy

The reason you can't use javascript to inspect the cookie is because the cookie (correctly) has httpOnly: true. That means only the server can inspect it. However do not change this, as you need httpOnly: true, otherwise you would get security vulns. The way to check is via dev tools, and like you said its there, which aligns with my theory.

The problem is that when you hit your site, it sets isLoggedIn via making a call to /login and checking if its 200. However it makes this call instantly as soon as the app loads. When the app loads (or page fully refreshes), it submits the form with empty username and password -- since they are just data in memory that is gone on hard refresh. The server returns with 400 since the /login endpoint cant receive empty user/pass. The UI code then considered isLoggedIn to be false.

Essentially, it doesnt make any sense to have the /login API endpoint be called when the component loads inside an effect. You cant use the /login endpoint to detect if they are logged in. You instead need a new GET endpoint on the API like /user/me or /auth (doesn't matter about the name). This endpoint would simply check that req.user exists, and if it does it would return true else false. Then, this would be the API endpoint to call when the component loads and set isLoggedIn based on the response. The call to /login API should be on login form onSubmit only.

Essentially /login endpoint is for performing the action of "logging in". It can not be co-opted to detect "am I already logged in". You need a new endpoint for that.

I can post an answer but would be easier to have the entire unedited code around the first snippet in your post for context. At the moment, its an almagamation of snippets and not valid code which makes it harder for me to be more specific. Post the whole files/components with those bits of code. :)

@adsy  So actually the form submission was onSubmit indeed. The /login point will call once I submit the form, but if I create like you said:app.get('/user/me', verifyJWTtoken, async (req, res) => {
let user = await UsersModel.findById(decode.userID);
if (!user) {
return res.status(400).json({
loggedIn: false,
user: null
});
}
res.status(200).json({
loggedIn: true,
user: req.user,
});
});When should I call this point? Like I will call the /login route once I submit the form, but what about this point?

@adsy Part 2:Can I call this point in App.jsx, which is the main component that gathers all component routes, using useEffect() on that with an empty dependency array? Maybe I could send a response as isLoggedIn as true or not, so I need to create a context for this? Depending on isLoggedIn, I need to change my UI. Should I use this in useEffect in App.jsx? Also, in login.js (backend), I don't need to use the find() method, right?Thanks!

Right exactly! Yes the ideal place to call it is high up in the tree like the App component. That's exactly the approach. Yes usually, you will also have some related context. One way of doing it is have the endpoint return the current users details if logged in and put that in the context. Note though, you then need to protect the routes that require authorisation.  Its common to create a ProtectedRoute component that wraps Route. This would check if they are logged in by looking in the context you mentioned and render a <Redirect> if they are not logged in that goes to logon.

The <Route> for the Login component would not use the new <ProtectedRoute> as it is accessible even if they are not authed. As for how to deal with logging in itself, since you are using cookie auth, it is quite common to just do a window.location.href browser side redirect to trigger a full page refresh on successful logon to the desired home page. Then it would trigger the app to go and fetch the user. This sounds cumbersome, but it does "reset" the state to the reality of what is on the users session serverside and so is a robust approach.

If youd rather not have a full page refresh on logon, you can instead either a) put a callback into the new context so the logon page can use it from there and cause the new "is authed" endpoint  to trigger programmatically. Or b) Have the logon API send the same object as the new "is authed" endpoint back when its successful, and use a callback you put into the new context so that you can then set that back up into the "auth context provider" programmatically.

I just want to add a further clarification. Above i said "the ideal place to call it is high up in the tree like the App component.". This is pretty much the same thing, but you'd usually have some AuthProvider component that has the AuthContext.Provider inside of it for the context we discussed, and that AuthProvider component would have the useEffect that calls the new endpoint. Then AuthProvider would wrap everything (used in App.jsx to wrap all of its innards). Practically speaking this is just code organisation. It holds true, yes, you do this at a "high level" in the tree.

@adsy hi , thank u so much for the conversation . and i done the login , without u r help i wont even do that cuz i tried in chatgpt and some discord server as well but none of it works , i had one question , i dont have any /admin or dashboard like any important so then i no need to preotect components right ???  and also should i use useNavigate or complete refresh as u said using window.location.href , whic is better after user/me route ? like to go /home  but thanks for all of this

So its up to you if the components themselves need to be hidden from view when logged out. But usually this code is not interesting by itself. The true value of an app is from the back end data usually. So the answer is probably no, you do not need to take steps to hide the view code. After all, someone can probably just register and get that anyway in 2 clicks. Its not usually "secret" or that interesting to some kind of attacker.

As for which way is better -- honestly just to get you up and running I'd just do window.location.href for now in this specific instance so you don't need to mess around with updating the logged in user from a child component. You can always change this later. Note this is just for the login redirect, everything else should use react router hooks. And no worries on the help :). The issue with chatgpt is it is thinking about the issue in isolation and is unable to realise the bigger picture which is an architecture question and not actually a simple "code challenge" type thing.

@adsy yes I tried window.location.href , thanks but how do u remove a cookie of jwt token I tried like res.clearCookie('token') and it works but it only clear on its path routes but not clears on '/' path , i tried also like res.clearCookie('token',{ path:'/'}) , i saw some website and I saw it can't be deleted , i m Asking some out of topics sorry

Whats the use case (why do you want to delete it)?

@adsy Logout functionality

Hmm so on the call to the logout endpoint do you have withCredentials set to true?

no i didnt set that
const res=await axios.post(${process.env.REACT_APP_URL}/logout);
if(!res){
throw new Error("Error while logging out")
}
if(res.data.isLogout === true){
setisLoggedIn(false);
Cookie.remove('token');
navigate('/delivery') // if i use window.location.href it would refresh and login
}

Ok I think you do need to set that on this call to logout from the UI via axios options withCredentials: true

@adsy I did this it removes and set the cookie as='' empty but after I refresh it logs in , like it's going again from the start but Thanks for all this conversation and have a great day, u helped me alot and I deployed my first mern project
